# Javascript: Why does my every() method return false when all the values of the array appear to meet the methods criteria?

Tags: javascript, arrays, boolean, each

I am trying to understand why the every method I am using returns a false boolean value. Here is my code:

```
let box1 = document.querySelector(`.box1`);
let box2 = document.querySelector(`.box2`);
let box3 = document.querySelector(`.box3`);

let array = [box1.value, box2.value, box3.value];

box1.value = `X`;
box2.value = `X`;
box3.value = `X`;

array.every((el) => el === `X`));
// This returns false
```

Is there something I am misunderstanding about the every() method? It seems like the values for each element of the array satisfy the condition set by the every() method, so why does it return false?

Comment: Because you're changing `box.value` **after** you've inserted it into the `array`.

Comment: Safe assumption that box 1-3 are defined above this snippet?  If so, can you please fix the question with an [edit]?

Comment: Also, to expand on what nem035 said, you're creating the array with the values of the properties, as opposed to the objects themselves.  If you were to create the array with the objects, then compare the property, everything would work as you expect.

Answer (score 2):

Because you're changing `box.value` **AFTER** you've inserted it into the array.

```js
let box1 = { value: 1 };
let box2 = { value: 2 };
let box3 = { value: 3 };

// since `value` points to a primitive
// that primitive is copied into this array
// so box1.value and array[0] are both pointing
// to an integer 1 but it's not the same integer!
// the value is the same but the location in memory is not
let array = [box1.value, box2.value, box3.value];

// this will only change the boxes
// but won't affect the `array`
box1.value = `X`;
box2.value = `X`;
box3.value = `X`;

// since the array contains a copy of each value
// from the box, the changes above only affect
// the boxes but not the array itself
console.log(array); // 1, 2, 3
```

Comment: It doesn't actually matter that it's a primitive, and I'd even argue that it's the same integer - they are indistinguishable for all purposes. What really matters is that the value held by the `.value` property is copied into the array, and updates to that property are not updating the array.

Comment: Sure thing. I know that with string interning it does become the exact same string but not sure if JS does that for numbers, I would guess so.

Comment: As far as if it matters that it's a primitive, it kind of does because if it were an object you could still do `box1.value.thing = 'b'` and change the original data and affect `array`

Comment: But yeah, the "copying" itself would happen, just on a reference instead of a value in that case.

Comment: Sure, but that is then updating the object, not the box. Even if the box had held an object, you could do `box1.value = {}` and it would not affect the reference that had been copied into the array.